# Copying Certain Rows to an Email Based on Criteria While Leaving the Original Worksheet Unmodified

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet used for ordering materials with multiple suppliers. When I have rows expressing a quantity needed, I would like to have a button to run a macro that copies only the rows with quantities and for a certain manufacturer to be copied to the body of an Outlook email without modifying the spreadsheet.

I have an object button that runs a macro that will copy all the visible cells from the spreadsheet to the email body. When I apply a filter to the range it modifies the spreadsheet.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:F20").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Order to be Placed"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"


    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With


    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With


    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")


    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False


    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

This macro works except it puts all of the visible cells in the email. When I apply a filter it modifies the spreadsheet. I tried the following:

```
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F5:F19")
For Each cell In rng
If cell.Value = "anixter" Then
    cell.EntireRow.Copy
```

This just hangs the process.

Comment: You can't. Applying a filter changes the worksheet, that's just how it is. Merely *activating/selecting a worksheet* marks the workbook as "dirty". What does it matter though, if you're closing it *without saving changes*?

Comment: I don't see where you are applying the filter in your code? If you haven't applied any filters, all cells in your range will be visible

Comment: Adding to @MathieuGuindon comments, just because your worksheet is **dirty** doesn't necessarily means that the data in the sheet has changed. Filter just hides some rows (as applicable), it doesn't mean that you have lost the data

Comment: I left the macro with the filter out of the question...I didn't want the field to be too busy so I just included the macro that copies to the email. That makes sense about applying a filter and the spreadsheet being modified regardless. I guess what I need to do instead is instead of copying all the rows to the email body, just the rows that match required criteria. I am trying to keep the original spreadsheet from being modified so it can be a template. I would like to use this same spreadsheet the next time I place an order but it may have different quantities and different particular items.